# Kali linux no internet in terminal but browser works fine

Tags: linux, internet, vmware-workstation, kali-linux, network-interface

Kali linux 2018 amd64 in VM Workstation

Since the last few days, I cannot connect to internet in terminal.
Internet works fine in tor & firefox browser, but I can't make an update in terminal.

I tried `apt-get update`

Result:

```
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « http.kali.org »
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
W: Impossible de récupérer http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Ne parvient pas à résoudre « http.kali.org »
W: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

Few days ago everything was ok.

So I check `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
*This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).*

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

*The loopback network interface*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

*The primary network interface*
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I also check NetworkManager file :

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

I restart `sudo service network-manager restart`

but problem still persists

I also ping

```
root@kali:~# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Nom ou service inconnu
```

If anyone can help thanks.

Comment: Kali is meant for network hacking. If you can't solve this kind of problem by yourself, you aren't part of its intended audience.. See the `ip` command to list your interfaces and their states, the `resolv.conf` file to check you DNS resolution (if it says 127.0.0.1 then use `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` to list your name servers for each interface). Is your browser using a proxy?

Comment: Hi ! thanks for your answer. I know what's kali is of course, i work with backtrack before... i use tor, so with tor browser the internet connection is on, but after a new try with firefox and terminal it seems to be down. On my VM machine it's set to NAT as usual, i always choose this option and everything was fine.

Comment: Resolv.conf : # Generated by NetworkManager
search localdomain
nameserver 192.168.206.2

Comment: Finally i found a solution by doing this : sudo systemctl enable resolvconf and
sudo systemctl start resolvconf

Comment: Put that as an answer... That will make your question shown as answered. In a couple of days, you can even accept it yourself.

Comment: xenoid ??? Sorry to tell you that, but if you help people to trash them out after, it means no sense. If people were less aggressive and narrow minded, the world would be better ! :)

Comment: Where did I trash you? this a true honest-to-goodness suggestion, [recommended behavior on the SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212626/answering-ones-own-question). Have fun with Kali. Unlike many others, maybe you deserve it :)

Comment: @Xenoid sorry probably misunderstood... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by doing this :

```
sudo systemctl enable resolvconf
sudo systemctl start resolvconf
```

Comment: I got this error `Failed to enable unit: Unit file resolvconf.service does not exist.`